# Got focus and lost focus both event calling repeatedly when handling get and lost focus event of multiple textboxes it goes into infinite loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

Following is my code to handle gotfocus and lostfocus event for all textboxes available in form.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                c.GotFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.txtGotFocus);
                c.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.txtLostfocus);
            }
        }
    }
    private void txtGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            tb.BackColor = Color.Silver;
            tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }

    }
    private void txtLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            tb.BackColor = Color.White;
            tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        }
    }
```

It works fine with first textbox but when I go to next textbox by pressing tab key it will repeatedly call both events and textbox behave like blinking. After some time error message display in code like:

> A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'System.Windows.Forms!System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+WndProc::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.

Whats wrong with code? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
   c.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.txtLostfocus);
```

LostFocus is a *dangerous* event, the MSDN Library article for Control.LostFocus warns about this and strongly recommends to use the Leave event instead.  This is something you can see in the designer, drop a TextBox on the form and click the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  Note how both the GotFocus and LostFocus events are *not* visible.  You must use the Enter and Leave events instead.

Some background on what is going on here.  Your program blows up because you assign the BorderStyle property.  That's a "difficult" property, it is one that affects the style flag of the window, the one that's passed to the native CreateWindowEx() function.  So changing the border style requires Winforms to create the native window again.  This is what causes the flicker you see, the text box is destroyed and re-created, then repainted.  You see that.

But that has side-effects beyond the flicker, it also causes the low-level GotFocus and LostFocus events to fire.  Because the destroyed window of course also loses the focus.  This interacts very poorly in your program since your LostFocus event handler changes the BorderStyle again, forcing Winforms to yet again recreate the window.  And fire the GotFocus event, you change the BorderStyle yet again.  This repeats over and over again, you see the textbox rapidly blinking.  This doesn't go on endlessly, after 10,000 times of creating the window, the operating system pulls the plug and doesn't let your program create yet another one.  The hard crash on the window procedure is the outcome.

Not a problem with the Enter and Leave events, they don't work from the low-level Windows notification so don't fire when the textbox window is recreated.  You can only get rid of the one-time flicker, if it is still bothering you, by not changing the BorderStyle property.

Comment: Thank you for useful information. This thing help me.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs cause you change the borderstyle. Dont ask me why, i dont know it. If you remove  `tb.BorderStyle = XXX` it will work. I guess(!) changing the borderstyle makes the control loose its fokus (and get it again)

Edit: Hans was faster, with a much better explanation :)